# const_cast a const member in a class constructor

Tags: c++, constructor, constants

I sometimes use const_cast when I want a member variable of a class to be constant during the life of the class, but it needs to be mutable during the constructor.  Example:

```
struct qqq {
 const vector<foo> my_foo;

  qqq(vector<foo>* other) {
    vector<foo>& mutable_foo = const_cast<vector<foo>&>(my_foo)
    other->swap(mutable_foo);
  }
};
```

I had assumed that doing this in the constructor was basically OK because nobody else is relying on it at this point so it wouldn't interact badly with optimization, etc.

However recently someone told me this is "undefined behavior" and that it's basically illegal to mutate a const object after it's been constructed under any circumstance.

Can someone clarify?  Is this a bad / undefined behavior / thing to do?

Comment: You shouldn’t pass the vector `other` into the constructor as a pointer unless you explicitly want to allow the user to pass `nullptr`, and handle this case appropriately.

Comment: A `const vector` member seems rather odd. What does this accomplish different than having accessor functions return `const` references to the member?

Comment: Konrad: you could pretend the arg is a reference instead.  doesn't affect my question.

Comment: Praetorian: The vector shouldn't be modified after the qqq is created until the qqq is destroyed.  The const enforces that.

Comment: So it's protecting you from yourself? How can the vector be modified by a user of the `qqq` class unless you provide a way for that to be done?

Comment: @Praetorian Protecting from yourself (and from other developers who modify the code later) by enforcing invariants is a very wise thing to do as code grows large.

Comment: @Angew I wouldn't argue against `const` qualifiers unless you're talking about `const` data members. IMO they're are rarely worth the trouble. For instance, in the class above, the `const vector` prohibits the compiler from generating the move constructor and copy / move assignment operator. Even if you write these yourself, you'll have to resort to `const_cast`, which is UB as you've stated in your answer. You, or other developers, modifying the code at a later date should not be doing so without first familiarizing yourself with the code.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**It is Undefined Behavior**. Per Paragraph 7.1.6.1/4 of the C++11 Standard:

> Except that any class member declared `mutable` (7.1.1) can be modified, any attempt to modify a `const`
>   object during its lifetime (3.8) results in undefined behavior.

In this case, it seems like you want your object to "become" constant after construction. This is not possible.

If your `vector` is meant to be `const`, you shall initialize it in the constructor's [**initialization list**](http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/initialization-lists-c++.html):

```
qqq(vector<foo>& other) 
    : my_foo(std::move(other)) 
//  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
{
}
```

Notice, that unless you have a good reason for passing by pointer - in which case, you should also be checking whether the pointer is non-null - you should consider passing by reference (as shown above), which is the common practice.

**UPDATE:**

As Pete Becker correctly points out in the comments, proper design would suggest that the decision to move from the `vector` argument should belong to the *caller* of `qqq`'s constructor, and not to the constructor itself.

If the constructor is always supposed to move from its argument, then you could let it accept an rvalue reference, making it clear what the constructor itself is expecting out of the caller:

```
qqq(vector<foo>&& other) 
//             ^^
    : my_foo(std::move(other)) 
//  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
{
}
```

This way, the caller would have to provide an *rvalue* in input to `qqq`'s constructor:

```
std::vector<foo> v;
// ...
qqq q1(v); // ERROR!
qqq q2(std::move(v)); // OK! Now the client is aware that v must be moved from
```

Comment: The decision to move should be made by the **caller**, not the callee.

Comment: @PeteBecker: Right. I expanded my answer.

Comment: But the `move` inside the constructor isn't needed, is it? It's already an rvalue reference; if the target type (here, `vector<foo>`) has a move constructor, that's what will be used.

Comment: @PeteBecker: `other` is an rvalue reference, but it is itself an lvalue, because it is a named object. So `std::move` is still necessary

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it's indeed UB (Undefined Behaviour). You cannot modify a `const` object once it's initialised. What you should do is use the member initialiser list, perhaps together with a function:

```
struct qqq {
  const vector<foo> my_foo;

  qqq(vector<foo> *other) : my_foo(initialiseFoo(*other)) {}

  static vector<foo> initialiseFoo(vector<foo> &other) {
    vector<foo> tmp;
    other.swap(tmp);
    return tmp;
  }
};
```

A decent optimiser should be able to get rid of the temporary.

If you can use C++11, it's actually even simpler:

```
struct qqq {
  const vector<foo> my_foo;

  qqq(vector<foo> *other) : my_foo(std::move(*other))
  {
    other->clear();  //Just in case the implementation of moving vectors is really weird
  }
};
```

Comment: Why not just `std::move` the vector in the initializer list?

Comment: @Praetorian I was already in the process of typing the C++11 version when you commented.

Comment: @KonradRudolph Does the standard *guarantee* that the move clears the container moved from? I know it's pretty much implied by the complexity, but isn't technically `*other` left in a "valid, but unspecified state?"

Comment: @Angew How does it matter? And why should you care what state `other` is left in? All that's relevant is that the caller shouldn't make any further use of `other` in its current state, after this object has been constructed.

Comment: @Praetorian I did it to preserve the original semantics (at least those it would have without UB), which left `*other` in a clearly defined state - empty (by being swapped with a default-constructed `vector`).

Comment: @Angew Accessing it – in fact, probably already the fact of calling `clear` is either undefined or unspecified (not sure which). So it *must* be irrelevant whether it is technically empty or not. The only valid operation that can be performed on the old vector is to reassign to it, or to destroy it.

Comment: @KonradRudolph I'm pretty sure calling `size()` on a vector after `clear()` is *guaranteed* to return 0, and it's legal to compare its `begin()` and `end()` etc.

Comment: @Konrad The object is in a **valid** (but unspecified) state. You can still call any member function, as long as you don't violate any preconditions of that function. `vector::clear` doesn't have any, so it's valid code. Angew: I still agree with Konrad's original assertion that the `clear()` is unnecessary. You, as the *callee*, should not be concerned with what the *caller* intends to do with the object after passing it to you.

Comment: @Praetorian Depends on the semantics of the interface. Emptying `*other` may or may not be a part of it.

Comment: @Praetorian True, I forgot about preconditions.